# Is there any way to read additional properties from PLY files?

Tags: import, file-format

The PLY format is very flexible, and it allows defining additional properties to the elements. For example, one could add a numeric, integer label to vertices.

Is there any way to read and visualize these properties?

Comment: You could modify the PLY importer to read them in as custom attributes. The whole importer is about 400 lines so it's easy to modify.

Comment: You could use a PLY to CSV converter, then use the indices in the mesh to find it's corresponding data in the CSV?

Comment: @Psyonic This could work for a vertex by vertex case, but I'm looking more for a visualization (i.e. color the mesh based on some property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the PLY file format is very flexible and expandable. However, currently it's not possible to import these extra properties within Blender. Not in the current Python importer, but also not in the new C++ importer that's currently in 3.6 alpha.

Stay tuned for that option to be added though. As someone who worked on the C++ implementation, I hope we can get it to work soon.

Comment: Thanks a lot for for this inside update. Is this effort public somewhere?